If I tie two well pressure tanks of unequal size together, what will be the resulting drawdown?
I currently have a 36 gal pressure tank, 10 gal drawdown. Due to slow well recovery I want to add a second larger tank 86 gal / 26 gal drawdown and tie them together. My question is, what will be the resulting drawdown?

Thanks, I understand it won' t fix the well. It's too complicated to go into here, I just need the answer to my question.

If you tie two tanks together at the same pressure, the combined drawdown will be roughly equal to the sum of the drawdowns at that pressure.  I.e. the two tanks will act as one tank of the combined size.  For a more exact answer, you can use a pressure tank drawdown calculator, treating the two tanks as one tank with their combined size.  The unequal sizes won't matter much.  You'll draw more water from the larger tank, because the smaller tank will lose pressure quicker.
As I previously commented, this is not the recommended solution.  A bigger tank will help you draw down more pressurized water before it needs to recover from the well.  But it will actually make the well recovery problem worse.  The larger tank will allow more drawdown and require more water to fill.  However, your well is already overwhelmed by the smaller drawdown that it faces now.  This will make the pump run less often but for greater amounts.  What you need is to run more often for smaller amounts to give the well time to recover.  A smaller tank would be better for that.
The recommended solution is a two stage system.  This would put two tanks in series with a pump between them.  The main pump from the well should run frequently but pausing after small amounts to fill the rear tank.  You would use water from the front tank and pump from the rear tank to keep it full and at pressure.  The main pump will slowly refill the rear tank.
That solution tries to keep pressurized water available all day, but the rear tank will be only partially filled most of the time.  It should fill overnight (if it doesn't, you need another well).
